# Rendering rows dynamically from this.state

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit green when it comes to `ReactJS` but it's part of a project I'm working on and I'm trying to understand how to properly mutate a component state:

I have a Table component, which is declared in ES6 as such:

```
class EmailStatisticTable extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            event_id: props.event_id,
            statistics: [],
            rows: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/events/' + this.state.event_id + '/emails/stats', function(resp){
            self.state.statistics = resp;
            self.state.statistics.forEach(function(statistic) {
                self.state.rows.push(<EmailStatisticRow statistic={statistic}/>);
            });
        });
        console.log(self.state.rows);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Recipient Type </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{this.state.rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

The idea here is that the rows would be rendered dynamically when `this.state.rows` changes. I can see that `self.state.rows` within the `componentDidMount` method is correctly creating an array of `EmailStatisticRow` components. Which is declared below:

```
class EmailStatisticRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            statistic : props.statistic
        }
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.state.statistic.record_type}</td>
                <td>{this.state.statistic.count}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

However, the rows are never added to the DOM after the data is sent back from the server through `$.getJSON()`.

I think my issue may be a fundamental misunderstanding of the `state` management and it's mutability/immutability in ReactJS.

Can anyone provide some clarity on this topic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be setting state via the setState() method rather than directly.

So replace:

```
self.state.statistics = resp;
            self.state.statistics.forEach(function(statistic) {
                self.state.rows.push(<EmailStatisticRow statistic={statistic}/>);
            });
```

With

```
this.setState({
  statistics: resp
})
```

And then rather than assigning the rows, in the render function replace

```
<tbody>{this.state.rows}</tbody>
```

with

```
<tbody>{this.state.statistics.map(function(row) {
  return <EmailStatisticRow statistic={row}/>
})}</tbody>
```

Edit: for a little further explanation - the setState will trigger a render and all the statistic rows will be mapped to EmailStatisticRow components.

Comment: Fantastic. This is the exact information that I needed to move forward. I can see where my errors were now. Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

In React [you should not mutate `state`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) directly like this:

```
self.state.rows.push(<EmailStatisticRow statistic={statistic}/>);
```

Instead, use `setState()`:

```
self.setState({rows: newRows});
```

It's also [not advised to store rendered elements in state](http://web.archive.org/web/20150419023006/http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state) (`<EmailStatisticRow>`), just store the `statistics` data in state:

```
self.setState({statistics: resp});
```

And render the list in your `render` function, for example using `map()`:

```
render () {
    return (
        <table className="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Recipient Type </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              { this.state.statistics.map(statistic => <EmailStatisticRow statistic={statistic}/>) }
          </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

Using `setState()` causes `render()` to be called, and render should always give you a full result based on the props and state. This is the basic rendering pattern of React that makes it predictable.